# Add a square box to the Image View and create 16 smaller boxes inside that box

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have to place a large box inside an image box. And inside this big box, 16 small but same size boxes are to be installed. Each box has to be given a separate ID. I am using the given zel code but i am not getting success. Can anyone help me in this regard?

I want to make Textbox in image view. So i send it through Whatsapp as image. I use following code.

[image]

```
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/saifimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />


   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sss"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="0"
           android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:background="@drawable/textborder"
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_500" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sss3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Sample Send"
        android:id="@+id/send">

         </Button>
```

Now how can i whats-app this image with text ?

Comment: Where are you using shape drawable code?

Comment: I have update my code and Question, Please check this and help me for sending whatsapp (Text on Image) as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully solved my problem myself. I placed the image box and text views in a RelativeLayout and then sent the message by converting the RelativeLayout to an image using the listed code.

```
     send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = findViewById(R.id.datarelative);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapee);
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(datarelative.getDrawingCache());

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            shareImageandText(bitmap);
        }
    });

    }
private void shareImageandText(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Uri uri = getmageToShare(bitmap);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    // putting uri of image to be shared
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    // adding text to share
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s1.getText().toString());
    // Add subject Here
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is Description message");
    // setting type to image
    intent.setType("image/png");
    // calling startactivity() to share
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
}

// Retrieving the url to share
private Uri getmageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagefolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        imagefolder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(imagefolder, "shared_image.png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.education.razanew.fileprovider", file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the issue in detail
by other option you can also use the gridlayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Large Box (Image) -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/largeBox"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/large_box_image" />

    <!-- Container for Small Boxes -->
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/smallBoxContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeBox">

        <!-- Small Boxes (repeat as needed) -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smallBox1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/small_box_image" />

        <!-- Add more small boxes here... -->

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have edit my question with details . Please check again.